# jQuery - Get the class names of a div's children and add numerical value of them together

Tags: jquery

I'm building a function based on Twitter Bootstrap's responsive grid. It uses `.row-fluid` as a container and `spans` as nodes that fit inside the rows. Each row can have a maximum of 12 'spans' in it.

I want my function to find any element with class `.row-fluid`, find its child nodes, take the class name, remove "span" from it (leaving only a number) and add those numbers together. If the result is bigger than 12, I'd like it to shrink the biggest number down until the number DOES equal 12.

Sounds complicated, hopefully I'm not TOO far off. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
$('.row-fluid').each(function() {
    var spanned = $(this).children('div[class*=span]').each(function() {
        var total = 0, nums = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);
        nums.each(function() {
            total += this;
        }
        console.log(total);
    }
    );
    console.log("break");
}
);
```

At present this is logging the WHOLE element rather than just the numbers so I'm at a bit of a loss as to where I've gone wrong/what to do from here. Any advice?

EDIT: The structure is similar to this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span5">

  </div>
  <div class="span4">


  </div>
  <div class="span2">

  </div> //Function should check if the 3 above spans <= 12
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span8"> //Function should see this and...
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div> //...this and see that they DON'T equal 12, then subtract 2 from the bigger span so that they DO equal 12
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could u provide sample html structure with those spans to clear it up a bit ?

Comment: @Fisher Sure, see my edit plus comments to say what the script hopes to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess, this is what you're trying to do :

```
$('.row-fluid').each(function(i,ele) {
    var total = 0;
    $(ele).children().each(function(i2, spans) {
        if (spans.className.indexOf('span') != -1) {
             total += parseInt(spans.className.replace(/[A-Za-z$-]/g, ""),10);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works, cheers. Can you please explain what `(i, ele)` does here? You don't use `i` in the function itself (nor `i2`) so I'm not sure what is being passed on here.

Comment: `$.each` has two parameters, the index and the element. You have to reference the index, if nothing else just to get to the element part. In other words `ele` and `spans` are pretty much the same as `this`, and `i` and `i2` is just an index (a counter in the loop).

Comment: Oh right so `each` is essentially creating a `for` loop and `i` is just the increment number. Got it, cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

`var total = 0, nums = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);`

Ugly line - define each var in separate line, because its easier to parse for human beeing ;]

`nums = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);`

This is string, not a number, do such thing instead:

```
var numString = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/);
var num = parseInt(numString);
```

Im not sure what happens here:

`nums.each(function() {`

but nothing good i assume ... each function is for jQuery elements, so maybe jQuery treat your nums as jQuery object

`total += this;`

Generally inside each parameter function, 'this' keyword is kind of jquery selector, thats why u gets elements instead of numbers

I would say that you need to declare total variable outside spans.each(), because u will get it cleared after each iteration + do sth like that:

`total += num;`

assuming u will parse numString to number, as i mentioned above.